# How am I mis-using closest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML that looks like this

```
<div id="1053906-cdm-contract-with-city-of-new-orleans-2013-fema" class="contract-container">
  <p class="contract-title contract">CDM- Contract with City of New Orleans: 2013-FEMA-3BCD COOPER GT TOWN DIXON CDM SMITH</p>
  <p class="contract-description contract">2013-FEMA-3BCD COOPER GT TOWN DIXON CDM SMITH</p>

   <div class="mention-text contract"><div class="page">Page 1</div> sometext </div> <br><br>


   <div class="mention-text contract"><div class="page">Page 16</div> some text</div> <br><br>


</div>
```

When a user clicks anywhere in the outer-most div, I want to find the closest "page". I use this jquery

```
firsthtml = $(this).closest(".page").html();
```

This returns "undefined" for `firsthtml`

If I get rid of the `.html()` and hover over the firsthtml var -- I see that it returns the HTML for the entire div. In other words it returns multiple divs with `class="page"`.

Why isn't it pulling only  the first class with "page"?

Comment: .closest only looks at ancestor elements, not sibling/children/cousins etc

Comment: *"When a user clicks anywhere in the div..."* ***Which*** div?

Comment: And, it doesn't make sense for it to be pulling more than one, i think you may be mis-interpreting that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see my edit. Outermost div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a difference between `.closest()` and `.find()` and what you're trying to do.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

`closest` and `find` navigate up and down the DOM tree.  If you wanted to get the HTML of `.page` you would have to say something like

```
$(this).find('.page').html();
```

Since `.page' is almost the last element in your div structure.

If you're looking to get the HTML of the FIRST `.page` element, that is different.  You'd have to say something like:

```
$('.page').eq(0).html()
```

`.eq()` is another way of saying `.index()` but it will select whichever element you want.  If you want to select that page inside that specific div, you could possibly do

```
$(this).find('.page').eq(0).html();
```